# Add Script tag in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gatsby

I have created a Gatsby website. To enable push notification in that website I have to use this code:

```
<!-- Begin DigitalPUSH code -->
<script>
var DGPkey = "M3E2cGU5d1hPQWl2VTRTeG9ZYU8xa0l1YW8yMWVmR3FKbFFjMGNLNllIbz0="; //mandatory
var DGPnativerequest = "0";
var DGPdelay = "10000";
var DGPmtype = "overlay";
var DGPtheme = "13e3b4";
var DGPtitle = "!!!  !!!";
var DGPmessage = "!!!  !!!";
var DGPallowbutton = "";
var DGPrejectbutton = "";
var DGPbgimage = "";
var DGPinpageads = "0";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.digitalpush.org/lib.js"></script>
<!-- End DigitalPUSH code -->
```

I have to put this code before the  tag. I tried couple of methods from the internet but none seem to work. Can someone please tell me how to do this?

My website's template:https://github.com/Tahsin007/classsed-gatsby-blog

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The script you are trying to embed (ostensibly to integrate push notifications) manipulates the DOM to display ads on the page. This will likely cause bugs since React does not expect DOM nodes under its control to change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### 2022 update

Since the release of the [`Script` Gatsby component](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-script/) (powered by Partytown) it's much easier adding third-party scripts. Just:

```
import React from "react"
import { Script } from "gatsby"

function YourPage() {
  return <Script src="https://my-example-script" />
}

export default YourPage
```

---

From what is extracted from Gatsby documentation about [using client-side packages/librares](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/using-client-side-only-packages/). I would suggest the following.

With React (and also with Gatsby) you can easily achieve this by using `<Helmet>` tag. Basically, it allows you to put `<scripts>` (or other metadata) in any component which will be placed in the `<head>` once compiled.  So, in your case:

```
    import React, {useEffect} from "react"
    import Helmet from "react-helmet"
    
    import Layout from "../components/layout"
    import SEO from "../components/seo"

    const AnyPage = () => (
    useEffect(()=>{
    var DGPkey = "M3E2cGU5d1hPQWl2VTRTeG9ZYU8xa0l1YW8yMWVmR3FKbFFjMGNLNllIbz0=";
    var DGPnativerequest = "0";
    var DGPdelay = "10000";
    var DGPmtype = "overlay";
    var DGPtheme = "13e3b4";
    var DGPtitle = "!!!  !!!";
    var DGPmessage = "!!!  !!!";
    var DGPallowbutton = "";
    var DGPrejectbutton = "";
    var DGPbgimage = "";
    var DGPinpageads = "0";
},[])
        return <Layout>
          <SEO title="AnyPage" />
          <Helmet>
            <script src="//cdn.digitalpush.org/lib.js"/>
          </Helmet>
        <div>Dummy content</div>
        </Layout>
    )
    
    export default AnyPage
```

You can find more information about `<Helmet>` tag and its usage in [their documentation](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet).

Here's a screenshot testing in my local machine:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering the question. I created a page named anypage.js and copied your code into that. But when I uploaded it to the server, it shows nothing. Is it putting the script tag before </body>?

Comment: I've updated my answer @Joel007 . There was an `import` missing (`useEffect` from React) and I've added a `<div>` with a dummy content. Answering your question. Now, you should see a "Dummy content" content. You can check if it's loading the `<script>` in the inspector but yes, it is loading before `<body>` tag, (it puts it inside `<head>`).